# Redirect file uploading request in Fine Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using Fine Uploader for uploading multiple files.
It's working fine.
But i want a little bit change.

I have a file name upload.php in which i have written a file uploading script in database.
I just want that after hitting upload button the request will go to my upload.php file and the files will be uploaded accordingly.

How i can achieve this ?

index.php

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger">

 <div class="buttons">
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
         <div>Select files</div>
    </div>

<button type="button" id="trigger-upload" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
</button>

</div>
 </script>
```

Javascript

```
   <script>
        var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
            template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/server/upload.php'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true
        });

        qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
            manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });
    </script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

require_once './include/db_connection.php';

if(!empty($_FILES)){

    $targetDir = "upload/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile))

   {
        //insert file information into db table
 $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Query not working';
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not grasping here.

Comment: exactly; I don't understand the question. You say it's working but you state: *"I just want that after hitting upload button the request will go to my upload.php file and the files will be uploaded accordingly.

How i can achieve this ?"* - Achieve what exactly? Do you mean "redirect" after it uploaded?

Comment: Yes, on hitting upload button, the request will redirect to upload.php

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php - you have a few options. This most likely being a possible duplicate of it.

Comment: Sir, i don't know where to write  the redirection code . I am using this plugin for the very first time. I don't know that what piece of code makes uploading

Comment: simply place the redirection just below the `$sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO files...` if the query is successful.

Comment: no no no..
wait.
I am using this plugin for the very first time.
When i clicked on upload button, i even don't know how this handles uploading.
After reading documentation i came to know that in javascript, by changing the "endPoint" you can handle the uploading.
In "endPoint", i mentioned my filename like "uplod.php" but the code is not working

Comment: on hitting upload button. the upload.php code should run. But this time, i don't know from where and  which piece of code is running